# .htaccess redirect to subdirectory on different domain while preserving the URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ok, I admit it, .htaccess does my head in but I can usually figure something out. This time I'm stumped and I can't find an example of the exact same thing elsewhere.

I want to redirect everything from one domain to a subdirectory of another domain while preserving the URI.

So, for example, I want www.domain1.com/thisuri.html to redirect to www.domain2.com/sub/thisuri.html

The closest I can get is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com/ [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/sub/$1 [P,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain2.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

But neither of them quite do what I want them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was close. This finally go it working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)? domain1\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www. domain2.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mod_proxy` enabled and working on `domain1` then this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

Comment: Same result as my attempt I'm afraid. It redirects to domain2.com but without the subdomain. ie: www.domain1.com/thisuri.html -> www.domain2.com/thisuri.html

Comment: If it is redirecting then `mod_proxy` isn't enabled on `domain1`. Flag `P` simply redirects for that case.

Comment: I just double checked. `mod_proxy` is definitely enabled.

Comment: As you can see there is no `R` flag in above rule. Flag `P` does external redirect only when `mod_proxy` isn't enabled. Test it separately and in a new browser.

Comment: No `R` flag, just `[P, L]`

Comment: Yes that is what wrote.

Comment: thanks for your help @anubhava. I actually cut and pasted what you replied (obviously changing the domain names) and it's definitely not working. I've tested it in different browsers and the `mod_proxy` module is definitely enabled.

Comment: But how do you know `mod_proxy` is enabled and working? Did you run some test to see it is working properly?

Comment: I checked the httpd.conf file and then asked our server guys to check who confirmed it is enabled and working.

Comment: Yes that is what I need to understand how did you test?

Comment: `§ httpd -M | grep prox
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)`

Comment: So how do I test it then?

Comment: I am not really a server admin but the fact that `P` flag is redirecting is the test that mod_proxy isn't working.